# Como desinstalar "todos" os pacotes baixados com pip?

Tags: python, pip

Bom, meu Pycharm passa muito tempo "Indexando arquivos", queria saber uma maneira de fazer ele encurtar ou parar com isso. **Uso windows**

Vi que ele passa a maior parte do tempo na pasta: "/Lib" do python (onde fica os meus pacotes baixados).

Queria desinstalar todos os meus pacotes baixados, e deixar apenas os que realmente uso, pois pela quantidade de tempo que o pycharm demora para "indexar" vem deles.

Já tentei desinstalar o python e instalar novamente, mas os pacotes que baixei continuam lá, como posso desinstalar todos os pacotes baixados com o pip de maneira mais rápida sem ser um por um? **e deixando apenas os necessários para o pip funcionar?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consigo ver duas forma de conseguir o resultado desejado.

1. Gerar um requirements.txt temporário, apenas para fazer a desinstalação dos pacotes
2. Excluir a pasta onde ficam os pacotes baixados e gerar ela novamente

Para resolver da maneira descrita em 1 vamos utilizar o comando [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/), ele vai gerar a lista de pacotes instalados. Que ficam organizados em ordem alfabética (tudo em minúsculos, [case-insensitive]) e a partir dessa lista fazer a desinstalação de tudo que está instalado em seu `ambiente virtual`. Para executar este comando estou supondo que está na pasta raiz do seu repositório e que o ambiente virtual está ativo (ter executado o comando activate ou `Scripts\activate.bat` (se for Windows).

```
pip freeze > requirementstmp.txt
```

Isso vai gerar um arquivo `requirementstmp.txt`.

Com este arquivo basta desinstalar todos os pacotes:

```
pip uninstall -r requirementstmp.txt -y
```

Este comando vai executar a desinstalação dos pacotes. Caso execute sem o parâmetro `-y` vai ter que confirmar a desinstalação 1 por 1. Veja mais opções na [`documentação`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_uninstall/).

Após ter desinstalado todos os pacotes com sucesso, pode remover o arquivo `requirementstmp.txt` pois ele não será mais necessário.

---

Para resolver da maneira descrita em 2, basta fazer a remoção do ambiente virtual e criar ele novamente. Para executar estes passos estou supondo que está com o ambiente virtual ativo.

```
deactivate
rm -rf <diretório-do-ambiente-virtual>
```

E depois criar o ambiente virtual novo

```
virtualenv venv -p $(which python3)
source venv/bin/activate
```

O comando virtualenv vai criar um novo ambiente de desenvolvimento baseado em seus executáveis do python3 e ao executar o comando `source` isso vai carregar o seu ambiente virtual

Em Windows, poderia remover o diretório pela interface gráfica e depois criar o ambiente virtual novamente, o equivalente a criar o ambiente virtual novamente seria:

```
python -m venv .
Scripts\activate.bat
```

No Windows executando `Scripts\activate.bat` vai fazer o seu ambiente virtual ficar no estado "ativo".